# .show() .hide() not working in FIREFOX, working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I am using 2 input fields, the first is the true one, the other will be hidden, just right behind it, using `position:fixed;` , when the user submits the form, there will be a Form Validation, if that original field is empty, the invisible input will show up, with a red background, with an alert message. this is working, by using `.show()` after it has had `display:none;`  then I wrote another code in jquery, which makes this alert input go away, when the user clicks at it, means he's trying to access back the original input so he can write in it, and this is working, by using `.hide()` ; the problem is, when I click submit again, the alert input isn't showing up...again, in firefox; but it's working completely good in IE.

Here is the HTML CODE:

```
 <div style="   padding-top:2px; overflow:hidden; float:left  ">
<div style="float:left; ">
<label for="email">
E-mail
</label> 
<br>
<div style="position:relative;">
<input class="inputtext" type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="32" style=" width:140px; height:15px;" tabindex=1/>
<input class="inputtext" type="text" id="emailnotification" name="emailnotification" maxlength="32" style=" width:140px; background-color: rgb(220, 20, 60); color: white; z-index:20; display:none; height:15px; font-weight: bold; position:absolute; left:0px;"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Now this is a part of the form validation function:

```
function validateForm()
{

    var xe;
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    var xemail=document.forms["signinForm"]["email"].value;
    if(xemail==null || xemail=="")
        {$("#emailnotification").val("Email is Required");  
        $("#emailnotification").show();

            xe=1;
        }
    else if (reg.test(xemail)==false)
        {   

            $("#emailnotification").val("Email is not Valid");
            $("#emailnotification").show();
            xe=1;
        }
```

now this is the jquery code which hide it back:

```
    $("#emailnotification").click ( 
function() { 
$("#emailnotification").hide(); 
$("#email").focus(); 
$("#emailnotification").blur(); 
});
```

Comment: _"not working in FIREFOX, working in IE"_ it works in IE but not in FF? **I'm closing it for not a real question...** :)

Comment: @gdoron Firefox is super buggy, it will be the new IE in another year, and Chrome will be the new Firefox.

Comment: @gdoron clearly just a propaganda post by the same person who made that stupid IE commercial thats playing everywhere...

Comment: I saw someone really voted to close the question for being _not a real question_ I hope it wasn't because of my joke...

Comment: propaganda for IE ??? I'm just testing my website with IE because most stupid people still use it. show and hide ARE WORKING, but show is only working once ! please read my description.

Comment: Instead of having a second input over the first one that is exactly the same as the first one, except, with a red background... Wouldn't it be more simple to add a red background to your first input, and remove it when the user focus the input? Your code looks complicated for nothing. (what's `var xe;` for?)

Comment: I tried it but its not that simple, there's color stuff, my input is well customized, it has different border color and text color if its idle, focused, or hovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Works here in firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/sybSu/)

Although I changed the code a bit...

`$("#emailnotification").blur();` is useless, since you focus elsewhere first.

(I also used Rodolfo suggestion)

Comment: the only difference between your code and my code is that you removed the z-index, I did the same, but using the TAB key, I kept pressing TAB, after clicking submit for the second time, clicking TAB led to the focusing on the second input which I couldn't see, the original input was moved above it, there's still a problem !!!

Comment: Ok OK I fixed it, instead of using position:absolute and keeping the main input even after submitting, i switched between them, when one is showen, the other is hidden, thanks all

Comment: plus this helps tricky people who use TAB to get access to the "hidden" input which actually its not hidden

Comment: @AliBassam just remember to mark this as answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is in `var xemail=document.forms["signinForm"]["email"].value`  ...  have you checked with an alert if `xemail` is the same in IE and FF?  I think FF and IE use form things differently. Just to check try giving 'email' an id and use that to refer it instead, like `var xemail = $("#email").val()`

Comment: JUST about to say the same thing. Use `$('#email')` or `$('#signinForm #email')` if there's more than one form.

Comment: well even if there's more than one form, #email would be unique

Comment: same problem bro, it works for only 1 time, it shows for the first time, when I click back to hide it, its hidden, but when I click submit again, it doesn't show again

Comment: @Rodolfo doh, of course. Ali Bassam: You might also try changing the color of your 2nd input box to something other than "white."

Comment: But it has a Crimson background, does it make a difference?